# Posting to a Facebook Page from a Google Apps Script using a System User token results in OAuthException

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently trying to automate social media posts from a Google Spreadsheet to a Facebook Page using Google Apps Script. The script is designed to read data from the spreadsheet, then use the Facebook Graph API to post the content to a specific Facebook Page.

Here is a simplified version of the Google Apps Script function that makes the POST request:

```
function postToFacebook(image_url, caption) {
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    'payload' : `url=${encodeURIComponent(image_url)}&caption=${encodeURIComponent(caption)}&published=true&access_token=${ACCESS_TOKEN}`
  };
  
  const container = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/<FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID>/photos';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(container, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

**However, I consistently receive the following error message:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not available. It has been deprecated. If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "<TRACE_ID>"
  }
}
```

In Facebook's Business Settings, I've confirmed that the System User has been granted an 'Admin' role on the Page under "Assigned Assets" and has pages_manage_posts and pages_read_engagement permissions. The app is currently in live mode.

Interestingly, if I replace the System User token with a Page Access Token obtained from the Graph API Explorer, the script works perfectly. However, I'd like to use a long-lived System User token for this automation.

Is there a step I'm missing to allow a System User token to post to a Page, or does this functionality not exist? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The documentation on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/ say "Requirements: A Page access token requested by a person who can perform the CREATE_CONTENT task on the Page"

Comment: Thanks @WizKid got it done from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/system-users/guides/api-calls

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to using the system user's access token instead of the specific access token of the page where the post was to be made.

Firstly, it's important to understand that the system user and the Facebook page are separate entities, each having their own access tokens. While the system user access token can be used to fetch data related to the system user (such as the pages it has access to), to perform actions on a specific page (like posting a photo), you need to use the page's own access token.

Here's a solution to fetch the page access token and post to the page:

```
// Replace this with your system user access token
const SYSTEM_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'your-system-user-access-token';

function getPageAccessToken() {
  const url = `https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/me/accounts?access_token=${SYSTEM_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN}`;
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  // Find the page you want to post to
  const page = data.data.find(page => page.id === 'your-page-id');
  if (!page) {
    throw new Error('Page not found');
  }

  return page.access_token;
}

function postToFacebook(image_url, caption) {
  const pageAccessToken = getPageAccessToken();
  
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    'payload' : `url=${encodeURIComponent(image_url)}&caption=${encodeURIComponent(caption)}&published=true&access_token=${pageAccessToken}`
  };
  
  const container = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/your-page-id/photos';
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(container, options);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Just replace 'your-page-id' with the ID of your page, and 'your-system-user-access-token' with your system user's access token.

Additional documentation on System User and API calls can be found on the [Facebook Developer's Website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/system-users/guides/api-calls).